# Trouble understanding closures/scope in nested events in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kml, mapbox, gpx

I'm writing an app in angular and have to determine whether or not a layer can be loaded as GPX or KML (geographic data XML files). Then I return the layer that it was successfully loaded as. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set a variable to true when I am within the .on(ready) event (the success event). Here is my code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('TractNotes')
    .factory('xmldataService', xmldataService);

xmldataService.$inject = [];

/* @ngInject */
function xmldataService() {
    var isKML = false;
    var isGPX = false;

    var service = {
        getxmldata: getxmldata
    };
    return service;

    ////////////////

    function getxmldata(layer) {
        var kml = omnivore.gpx('this will fail')
            .on('ready', function() {
                isKML = true;
            })
            .on('error', function() {
                console.log("This is not a KML layer.")
            })

        var gpx = omnivore.gpx(layer)
            .on('ready', function() {
                isGPX = true;
            })
            .on('error', function() {
                console.log("This is not a GPX layer.")
            });

        if(isKML){
            return kml;
        }
        else if(isGPX){
            return gpx;
        }
        else{
            return 'invalid file';
        }
        // @TODO: use desc xml tag as layer name
    }
}
})();
```

When the code runs, the console.logs work correctly BUT it never returns anything because the booleans are never properly set. Any help understanding this is appreciated.

leaflet-omnivore docs: https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's not that easy. When you run your service function the 'ready' event didn't fire yet, so the bool values are in false state. So they return 'invalid file'. I'd suggested to refactor your service to return a Promise instead of value. Take a look at that [Promise on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Then execute your code when promise resolved.

**Upd:**

Here, take a look at example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexEmashev/oy06ej1w/4/)

```
function xmlDataService() {
  var service = {
    getxmlData: getxmlData
  };
  return service;

  function getxmlData(layer) {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Promise started');
        var serviceCreated = false;
        var optionsCount = 2;
        var optionsFailed = 0;

        // First service
        window.setTimeout(
          function() {
            if (!serviceCreated) {
              serviceCreated = true;
              resolve('First service created');
            }
          }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000); // at least a second

        // Second Service
        window.setTimeout(
          function() {
            if (!serviceCreated) {
              serviceCreated = true;
              resolve('Second service created');
            }
          }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And on scope:

```
$scope.createService= function() {
  $scope.message = "Creating a Service";
  var promise = xmlDataService.getxmlData();
  promise.then(function(val) {
    console.log('Promise resolved');
    // Apply result on scope, since it been executed out of scope.
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.message = val;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...going to try to refactor now

Comment: Ended up using Jquery to determine if the layers were valid or not. From there resolving the promise worked correctly